# C# - The best way to popup window in datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a requirement as below. I have an excel file and i only need the header of the columns to be displayed in datagridview. I've arranged the header vertically in a column. My question is, when i hover to the name of the column (for example; when i hover to "A"), what is the best/efficient way to be able to see the data in that column? I'm thinking some kind of pop up from another form to display/preview the data in that column. Or do you have a better way than this? Thank you in advance.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the ToolTip Property of the cell for this.

```
private void setToolTipTexts()  
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells[0].Value != null)
        {
            string columnData = GetDataFromExcel(columnNumber); // columnNumber still has to be determined by you. As well as the method to get the data from excel.
            row.Cells[0].ToolTipText = columnData;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers Thomas

Comment: I will try to take a look on this. Thank you Thomas!

Comment: If you have many rows in your DataGridView you might find that it takes a long time to set all ToolTips.
you can add a check, if the row is currently displayed with:
if(this.dataGridView.Rows[i].Displayed)...

But then you have to add the setToolTipTexts Method call to the scroll event of the DataGridView

Comment: I think this is more or less is what i want. Thank you!